# Impulse and Step Function

Tags: functions

I know that the derivative of unit step function u(x) is the impulse function $\delta(x)$. So what is the derivative of u(-x)? Here is my guess but I am not sure: $\frac{d}{dx}u(-x)$ = $\frac{d(-x)}{dx}*\delta(-x)$ = -$\delta(-x)$ = -$\delta(x)$ I am using the chain rule. Is this correct, or if its is wrong can anyone give another answer that is correct with explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs a little care with distributions.

Formally, if $T$ is a distribution and $\phi$ is a test function, we define the
derivative of the distribution as $T'(\phi) = - T(\phi')$.

Here we have $V(\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) 1_{(-\infty,0]} dx $,
so $V'(\phi) = - V(\phi') = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) 1_{(-\infty,0]} dx = - \phi(0)$.

Since $\delta(\phi) = \phi(0)$, we see that $V' = - \delta$.

Comment: so is the answer -$\delta(x)$?

Comment: Yes. Many of the normal rules still hold true as you have observed, but the above is how you would prove it formally.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks